# Are you able to set constructor priority across modules in C?

Tags: c, gcc

Are you able to set constructor priority across modules in C?

For example, say I have the following three files:

(1) hw.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "main\n");
}
```

(2) libhw.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor(104)))
void my_constructor4(void)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "my_constructor4\n");
}
```

(3) libprio.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor(101)))
void my_constructor1(void)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "my_constructor1\n");
}

__attribute__((constructor(102)))
void my_constructor2(void)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "my_constructor2\n");
}

__attribute__((constructor(103)))
void my_constructor3(void)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "my_constructor3\n");
}
```

And then I compile things with:

```
gcc -O0 -Wall -g -shared -fPIC libhw.c  -o libhw.so
gcc -O0 -Wall -g -shared -fPIC libprio.c  -o libprio.so
gcc -O0 -Wall -g hw.c -o hw -L. -lprio -lhw
```

If I run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./hw` the output is:

```
my_constructor4
my_constructor1
my_constructor2
my_constructor3
main
```

I would like to see the following output:

```
my_constructor1
my_constructor2
my_constructor3
my_constructor4
main
```

Thus, I am wondering if the constructors can be run in order of priority even if they are in different modules/libraries regardless of the order they are passed to the linker.

Comment: I think the constructors in a shared library get run when that library is loaded.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes I believe you are right, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some method I could use to order them.

Comment: As shared libraries, they should be independent of each other, in which case it shouldn't matter which one's constructors run first.

Comment: Is might be good to point out that `__attribute__` and `constructor` are a gcc thing, not a Standard C thing, right?

Comment: If I had two constructors that just *had* to run in a certain order, and if I couldn't manage to remove that dependency any other way, I think I'd write my own code to explicitly guarantee it, not rely on something like ordering of files in a Makefile, which someone else might accidentally change on me later.

Comment: @SteveSummit it might not be a Standard  C thing, but the above also works for `clang`.

Comment: You could use dynamic library loading (man dlopen). This way, you'll have a strict control on the initialization order.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the constructors seems tied to the order in which the libraries are loaded, which in turn seems to be dependent on the linking order when the executable is created.  If you switch the linking order you should get the desired constructor order.

```
gcc -O0 -Wall -g hw.c -o hw -L. -lhw -lprio
```